# How to pause on a keyframe then continue playing after a set of time?

Tags: flash, actionscript

Hello my question now is how to pause on a keyframe for five seconds in flash then continue playing? I do not want to use a button at all. My code is: 
`function wait() { stop(); var myInterval = setInterval(function () { _level0.menu_number2 = 0; gotoAndStop(41); clearInterval(myInterval); }, 5*1000); }`
then on key frame 41:
`wait();
gotoAndPlay(41);`
What happens is that it dosn't pause. On keyframe 41 it goes into a loop by starting at key frame 41 then play five more seconds then goes back to key frame 41.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
stop();
setTimeout(function() { nextFrame(); }, 5000);
```

Comment: thx. I'm knew to actionscript and flash so I don't know much.